# Finding the solution of simple equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the possible positive solutions of the following equation group:
 $$\dfrac{a_{11}}{a_1}=\dfrac{a_{10}}{a_0}$$

$$\dfrac{a_{00}}{a_0}=\dfrac{a_{01}}{a_1}$$

$$a_0+a_1=1$$

$$a_{00}+a_{01}=a_0$$

$$a_{11}+a_{10}=a_1$$

$$a_{10}=a_{01}$$
where $a_0\,,a_1\,,a_{10}\,,a_{01}>0$

Comment: And what is stopping you?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I'd cosider the last four equations as a linear system, solve it, get 2 parameters and determine the parameter's values with the help of the first two equations-